# automatic click on identified object

Tags: python, yolo

this code makes the mouse move to the object that was identified when I press CAPSLOCK, I use yolo to detect the object
I would like the mouse to do the automatic left click when I hover over the detected object

```
              # Moving the mouse
                if win32api.GetKeyState(0x14):
                    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(
                        mouseMove[0] * aaMovementAmp), int(mouseMove[1] * aaMovementAmp), 0, 0)
                last_mid_coord = [xMid, yMid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are hovering over the object, just use the *mouse* module to make the mouse click.

```
import mouse
# left click
mouse.click('left')
```

Comment: not work with my code :/

Answer (score 0):

`win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0) time.sleep(.1) win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)`

This should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).